# What should I do after I got "Your AWS Free Tier Period is Expiring"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have started a wordpress website on Free Tier AWS(t2.micro Instance) in july 2020. My Free Tier plane is expired now and I got bill $13 for the same Instance I am using(on demand), that is ok to me.

But now I am planing to buy EC2 Instance Savings Plans, can anybody tell me, if I buy this plan then:
My same Instance will use in this EC2 Instance Savings Plan
or
I have to stop the old Instance and start new one.
It's bit confusing to me. Please help me thanks in advance :)

Comment: You might also consider moving to an Amazon Lightsail instance. The downside is that you'd need to create the instance again, but it has low-cost plans available.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to take any special action to apply a Savings Plan. You do not need to launch a new EC2 instance. According to the [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/) the savings get applied automatically to your existing EC2 instance(s).

By the way, you might also take a look at an [EC2 Reserved Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/) plan instead.
It's an older and less flexible offering from AWS, but would still apply to your use case. Particularly appropriate if you are not planning to change your EC2 instance type or region.

The same thing applies to Reserved Instances.. if you buy one it will automatically get applied. For a Reserved Instance, AWS will look for the first EC2 instance which matches the declared type and region.

You can check this from the CLI, if you run `aws ec2 describe-instances --region <<your-region>>` then you will see your reserved EC2 instance listed *inside* the reservation.